# How to combine a for loop with condition?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to python so let me know if I need more information, but here's what I have:

```
add=0
new=[]
for i in range(len(daytime['hours'])):
    if daytime['hours'][i]<=1:
        add=1
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
    if daytime["hours"][i]>1 and daytime["hours"][i]<2:
        add=2
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
    if daytime["hours"][i]>2 and daytime["hours"][i]<3:
        add=3
        daytime['hours'][i]=add   
    if daytime["hours"][i]>3 and daytime["hours"][i]<4:
        add=4
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
    if daytime["hours"][i]>4 and daytime["hours"][i]<5:
        add=5
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
    if daytime["hours"][i]>5 and daytime["hours"][i]<6:
        add=6
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
    if daytime["hours"][i]>6 and daytime["hours"][i]<7:
        add=7
        daytime['hours'][i]=add 
    if daytime["hours"][i]>7 and daytime["hours"][i]<8:
        add=8
        daytime['hours'][i]=add  
    if daytime["hours"][i]>8 and daytime["hours"][i]<9:
        add=9
        daytime['hours'][i]=add  
    if daytime["hours"][i]>9 and daytime["hours"][i]<10:
        add=10
        daytime['hours'][i]=add  
    if daytime["hours"][i]>10 and daytime["hours"][i]<11:
        add=11
        daytime['hours'][i]=add  
    if daytime["hours"][i]>11 and daytime["hours"][i]<12:
        add=12
        daytime['hours'][i]=add  
    if daytime["hours"][i]>12 and daytime["hours"][i]<13:
        add=13
        daytime['hours'][i]=add
```

I'm trying to make every data within an hour equal to the corresponding hour, but this is 13 if statements for 13 hours! I know there must be a way to *shorten it.*

I thought of doing add= i + 1 and adding on that, but it did not give me what I wanted.

The output **I have (And want)** is this: [Each activity is accordingly labelled with the hour range, first hour, second hour... until the 13th hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FYd4.png)

Comment: Did you consider [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)?

Comment: This is *not* "13 loops"; it is 1 loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter you're right, my bad! I'll edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to me like you want to round the number up to the upper range which is essentially the index + 1. The easiest way to do that is to use ceil() function from the math module. So first you do import math and then you can use someNumber = math.ceil(someNumber) to round the number up.

Kinda like this:

```
import math
for i in range(len(daytime['hours'])):
    daytime['hours'][i] = math.ceil(daytime['hours'][i])
```

Comment: hi, yes! that worked! Thank you so much :) I'd upvote your answer but I can't

Comment: Even though you can't upvote it, you *can* accept it: use the green checkmark.

Comment: I did! Thank you, I didn't know the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `math.ceil()` for this, which rounds numbers up. First you have to `import math`

Then in your for loop:

```
for i in range(len(daytime['hours'])):
    add = math.ceil(daytime['hours'][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you use normal python lists or numpy arrays.

If your `daytime['hours']` is a python list, then do:

```py
daytime['hours'] = [1 + int(hour) if hour%1 !=0 else int(hour) for hour in daytime['hours']]
```

which avoids importing math.

If it is a numpy array, do:

```py
daytime['hours'] = np.ceil(daytime['hours']).astype(int)
```

This is assuming you want your output as int.